# В гостях редакции или "У редакции"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее будет сказать: "Сегодня в гостях редакции..." или "сегодня в гостях У редакции..."?

Comment: И приношу извинения за резкость в посте о стихотворении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что У. В гостях (у кого?) у редакции. Или сегодня в редакцию такую-то пришел гость... Или приглашен...